# How does Carl see his own dead body?

Tags: the-endless

In the movie, The Endless, Carl is trapped in his own endless loop that lasts a few hours, after each loop, everything is reset within his own small sphere.

But how do we and himself manage to see his own already dead body hanging from his cabin? How does two Carls appear in the same loop?